# How can I make my CAPTCHA script have a refresh link?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, captcha

I have a captcha script and it works good. But, I don't know how to make it refresh.

Here's `verificationimage.php`:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$width = 50;
$height = 24;

$my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

// add noise
for ($c = 0; $c < 40; $c++){
    $x = rand(0,$width-1);
    $y = rand(0,$height-1);
    imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
    }

$x = rand(1,10);
$y = rand(1,10);

$rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
imagestring($my_image, 5, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);

setcookie('tntcon',(md5($rand_string).'a4xn'));

imagejpeg($my_image);
imagedestroy($my_image);
?>
```

And, the page with the form:

```
<label for="verif_box" style="margin-top:10px;">Image Verification:</label>

<input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" autocomplete="off" minlength="4" maxlength="5" class="text" />

<img id="captcha" src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="This form can't be submitted because images aren't displayed" title="Verification image, type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="absbottom" onclick="$('#verif_box').focus();" style="cursor:pointer;" /> &nbsp; (<a href="#captcha" class="fancybox">what's this?</a>)
<br />
<br />

    <?php 
    //if the variable "wrong_code" is sent from previous page then display the error field
    if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){?>
    <div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF; padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:295px;">The code you entered does not match the image. Please try typing what you see in the image to the right again.</div><br /> 
    <?php ;} ?>
```

Here is what happens in `mailer.php`:

```
// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
    // if verification code was correct send the message and show this page

    mail("email@domain.com", 'New WeeBuild Support Ticket: '.$subject, $emailContent, $headers);

    mail($email, 'Thank you for contacting WeeBuild Support! (#'.$ticket.')', $emailContents, $headers2);

    // add to database

    $today = getdate();
        $theDate = $today["weekday"].", ".$today["month"]." ".$today["mday"].", ".$today["year"];

    mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
        $sql="INSERT INTO table_name (name, email, subject, message, ticket, ip_address, created)
        VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[subject]','$_POST[message]','$ticket','$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]','$theDate')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  //close the database connection
  mysql_close($con);

    // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
    setcookie('tntcon','');

} else if(isset($message) and $message!=""){

    // if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error

    header("Location: index.php?name=$name&subject=$subject&email=".urlencode($email)."&message=".urlencode($message)."&wrong_code=true");
    exit;
}
```

It all currently works great, but how can I make the captcha refresh? I tried doing this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#refresh').click(function() {
$('img#captcha').attr('src','verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>');
});
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="refresh">refresh</a>
```

But, it doesn't work.

By the way, I don't want to use reCaptcha, I just rather do it this way because reCaptcha, to me, looks hard to set up with my stuff.

Comment: From a quick reading - you'll need to replace the `<?php echo rand` part with a javascript `Math.random`.  The php random number is evaluated before the page even gets sent to the user; every time they click it, it'll give them the same number.

Comment: @Sam Oh, thanks. I will try using `Math.random`. Hopefully it will work :)

Comment: @Sam Hmm, for some reason it wont work, you can see it here: http://weebuild.heliohost.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is similar to the one in the comments, likely a cached copy is being used on the refresh, but it'd be cleaner to use a proper method to make sure the browser doesn't cache that image rather than a random string. On the image generation page, add this:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: So I wont need a random number at the end anymore if I do it this way?

Comment: I actually just found a big problem that was causing this. I have 2 things with `#captcha` for it's ID. So I finally got it to work! :)

Comment: But, I am not using a random number anymore. I added your code to my PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, when I refresh it with that JavaScript, will it still match up with the cookie? Because as you can see in my `imageverification.php` code, it sets a cookie and does some other stuff to make sure the code is correct. But when you refresh it with that JavaScript, will it make it not match up anymore? It looks like it works but I don't know. I don't want it to give the error if they have it right after refreshing the image. http://weebuild.heliohost.org

Comment: @nathan The image's http response will drop a new cookie.. use something like LIVEHTTPHEADERS for firefox to verify this.

Comment: After all, I had to add a random number at the end because FF and IE thought it was the same image and didn't refresh.

Comment: @nathan Check the response headers and make sure they are getting sent properly. And you may have to clear your cache, because it probably made the choice to store them before you did your header modifications.

Comment: Other people tried it for me too before I added the random number, and it didn't work. It worked in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE. (Even IE9) So when someone refreshes, I just do this: `$('#captcha').attr('src','verificationimage.php?'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)+'');` I still have the no cache headers in though, but for it to work in IE and Firefox I had to add the random number when they refresh. Here's a screenshot of how I have the headers in: http://screencast.com/t/hPRKOS7w6r2 Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Since the image tag has an id, that's the only thing you'll need for the selector.
I think the problem comes from browser caching : because the random string is generated by **PHP** the refresh button will work only once (since the next calls will use the same string, the browser will use the cached version instead).

This should do the trick, a new random string is generated everytime the button is pressed :

```
$(function() {
    $('#refresh').click(function() {
        $('#captcha').attr('src', 'verificationimage.php?' + new Date().getTime());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Solved your problem I guess? Good for you :)

Comment: Well, I used profitphp's answer, but I was just saying thanks for answering :)

Comment: Because your answer gave me the idea to use `.attr()` and change the `src` instead of rewriting the whole `img` code with .html

Answer (score 1):

There are better, more secure ways to send the CAPTCHA information for verification besides using a cookie. At the very least, I would suggest using a session variable, but with a named session and IP verification, to prevent session hijacking. It would also be a VERY good idea to add hotlinking prevention to your CAPTCHA image generation script, so that someone can't just pull up the CAPTCHA image in a browser, all by itself. just a suggestion. :)

In order to use hotlink prevention, just add the following code to the top of the image creation script:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) or checkValidReferer() === false) die();

function checkValidReferer() {
  $out = false;
  $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $lh = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  if (stripos($ref,$lh) !== false) $out = true;
  return $out;
}
```

The above code outputs a good image, if the base URL of the referrer both exists, and is identical to the base URL of the image script. This prevents the image from being used somewhere other than where it's supposed to.

Comment: Well, it's just a ticket system and I don't feel like doing _all of that work_. But, I am interested in the hot linking prevention. How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to add multi-line code in the comments, so another answer in on the way. :)

Comment: Just did. Thanks. Still new to this place, even though I've come here for a while now, to find answers to problems.

Comment: Thanks Dave for that code! So I just add that to the top and it will make it not work when it's linked from another site? Awesome! :)

Comment: Also I saw [Captcha4Us](http://www.captcha4us.com/) and that's very neat. Great job on it :)

Comment: Thanks. I got tired of dealing with CAPTCHA images that were hard to figure out, so I made my own. When I mentioned it to some friends of mine, they insisted that I had something worth selling, so I decided to give it a try. :)

Comment: Yay! It worked! Thank you so much Dave! :) If you answer more questions, you'll get more reputation and have more privileges. Also, if you try linking to this image now, it shows the "image not available" symbol: http://weebuild.heliohost.org/captcha.php (but it works if linking to the image on the same server) Thanks again :)

Comment: I also made it show a custom image now :) So, it will show "Captcha Error" for anyone that tries to link to it. You can see for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/Axa3q/ Thanks again for this code! :)

Comment: I'm glad you were able to make use of the code. If you REALLY want to throw off the bag guys, instead of serving up NULL, like I do, or serving up an error image, as you're doing, you can also serve up a "fake" CAPTCHA image, and let the bot scripts go nuts trying to figure it out. :) Just a thought.